# React router not open 404 not found page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I created following with react router.

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Main extends Component {

render() {   
        return ( 
    <Router>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Content} />   
       <Route path='/user/:id' component={User} /> 
       <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
     </Switch>  
    </Router>
    );
}

export default Main
```

I want to open Notfound page if any invalid url.

I tried to open `localhost:3000/err` but, it will not go to NotFound compoenent.

My notfound component is simple.

```
import React from 'react';

const NotFound = () => (
    <h2>404 Page Not Found</h2>
);

export default NotFound;
```

I am using `"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1`

Comment: You say "*I tried to open localhost:3000/err but, it will not got to NotFound component.*". What do you get instead? I did just try to use your code (using `"react-router-dom": "^4.3.1`), and it works just fine (on `localhost:3000/err` I get "**404 Page Not Found**").

Comment: @MarcoS i got `Cannot GET /err`

Comment: Does your project compile successfully? I.e.: do you get something like `Compiled successfully!` on your `yarn start` command? And, above all, something like `You can now view my-app in the browser.` ?

Comment: @MarcoS Yes. `i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.`

Comment: Does `localhost:3000/` works fine?

Comment: Yes. It will open Content component and even second Rout also works fine  which open User compoenent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186712/discussion-between-marcos-and-ketan).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally, I solved by following solution.

Inside my webpack config file ( webpack.config.js ) i added following:

```
output: {
    publicPath: '/'
},

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for client-side routing to work, the server needs to always return the same index.html for all routes.

So, `localhost:3000/err` needs to return your index.html with the client-side router javascript.

Comment: I done following in my server.js file. `app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});`

Comment: do you see index.html coming back in devTools?

Comment: then, your server (express?) configuration is not correctly returning for all routes.

Comment: Actually i have following code.
`app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './index.html'));
});

app.listen(port, function (err) {
  if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        open('http://localhost:' + port);
    }
})`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Redirect? I am using this in my app and it works perfectly fine. Here is the updated code for your reference-

```
import {Route, Switch, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'; 

class Main extends Component {

render() {   
        return ( 
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path='/' component={Content} />   
       <Route path='/user/:id' component={User} /> 
       <Route path="/not-found" render={props => <NotFoundPage />} />
       <Redirect to="not-found" />
     </Switch>  
    );
}

export default Main
```

Enclose your App inside BrowserRouter.

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import App from './components/app.js'
import styles from './styles/style.css'
import { store } from './stores/store'

ReactDOM.render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'))
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Updated my answer a bit. This should definitely work.

Comment: Sorry. No luck. It even stops other component to render

Comment: It won't open not found page

Comment: I believe you have added the BroswerRouter in your index.js

Comment: You should add this to your file where you are bundling the entire app.

Comment: For example, I am doing this in index.js and importing App.js here.So in your case you should import Main.js and enclose Main component inside BrowserRouter.

Comment: It should work then.Probably something else is missing in your code. have to check the logs.

Comment: Just checking if you have you removed Router from your Main.js?

Answer (score 0):

```js
"react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
```

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path={[routes.user.details]} component={UserProfile} />
    <Route exact path={[routes.category.collection]} component={CategoryCollection} />
    <Route exact path={[routes.category.details]} component={CategoryDetails} />
    <Route exact path={[routes.product.collection]} component={ProductCollection} />
    <Route exact path={[routes.product.details]} component={ProductDetails} />

    <Route exact path={routes.auth.login} component={Login} />
    <Route exact path={routes.auth.register} component={Register} />
    <Route exact path={routes.auth.resetPassword} component={ResetPassword} />

    <Route
      path="*"
      component={() => {
        if (user.id) {
          return <Redirect to={routes.user.details} />;
        }

        return <Redirect to={routes.auth.login} />;
      }}
    />

  </Switch>
</Router>
```